# Python: Dictionary within dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need help with a pretty simple exercise I am trying to execute, just syntactically I'm a bit lost.

Basically I read in a very brief text file containing 15 lines of 3 elements (essentially 2 keys and a value)

- put those elements into a dictionary comprised of dictionaries
- the 1st dictionary contains location and the 2nd dictionary which is made up of the type of the item and how much it costs

For Example:

```
Location   Item     Cost
------------------------
gymnasium  weights  15 

market     cereal   5

gymnasium  shoes    50

saloon     beer     3

saloon     whiskey  10

market     bread    5
```

Which would result in

```
{'gymnasium': {'weights': 15, 'shoes': 50}
```

and so on for the other keys

Basically I need to loop through this file but I'm struggling to read in the contents as a dict of dicts. Moreover without that portion i can't figure out how to append the inner list to the outer list if an instance of the key in the outer list occurs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like homework, so I'll only provide a few hints.

You probably know that this is how you create a new dictionary:

```
d = {}
```

Adding an entry to a dictionary:

```
d[key] = value
```

More specifically, adding an entry whose key is a string and whose value is another dictionary:

```
d["gymnasium"] = {}
```

Now, whenever you write `d["gymnasium"]` as a part of a larger expression, you'll get access to that inner dictionary, and you can perform the usual dictionary operations on it, e.g. using `[]` and `=` to add something to it:

```
d["gymnasium"]["weights"] = 15
```

Comment: Great explanation. Also remember that since a key can be a string, a key can be inputted from a variable. For example, if I said `var = "weights"`, I could use that in the code `d["gymnasium"][var] = 15` to achieve the same effect as the last like of Aasmund's code.

Answer (score 0):

`collections.defaultdict` might be very useful to you, if you're allowed to use stdlib. It automatically creates any keys that don't already exist using a function you define, so:

```
import collections

dd = collections.defaultdict(dict)
dd['a']['b'] = "foo"
```

Will create a structure like:

```
{'a': {'b': 'foo'}}
```

If you can't use defaultdict, you'll have to either use `dict.setdefault` or test for membership before assigning to the deeper dict.

```
dd = {}
location, item, cost = ("gymnasium", "weights", 15)

# Either
if location in dd:
    dd[location][item] = cost
else:
    # dd[location] does not exist yet!
    dd[location] = {item: cost}

# Or
dd.setdefault(location, {})[item] = cost

# Or with defaultdict
ee = collections.defaultdict(dict)
ee[location][item] = cost  # creates automagically
```